# Kernel panic: No working init found

Tags: linux

I am trying to make a small media server out of an old PC.
I installed the OS (I decided to try Linux Mint for this) and everything was fine.
Done some setup, all good.
Then, out of the blue, I got this and not sure what to do.

[image: Kernel Panic]

Things worked fine and I did not install or change anything prior to this.
Ideas?

Comment: Is that a Wyse 7010/Z50D?

Comment: @GregAskew Wyse 7020. How did you figure that out?

Comment: I believe those had a semi special Linux build... Probably the only one running a modern os.

Comment: @GregAskew Yeah, it had something like that. Looked like something designed to connect to remote servers only. I wiped the drive and installed XP first, for retro gaming purpose, and now I wanted to test Plex server and this is the only disposable computer I have at the moment.

Answer (score 4):

The initramfs is corrupted. You need to re-geneate it using a rescue system and chroot into your machine. As mentioned by @tsc_chazz, it could be caused by a disk corruption. Could be a physical or just logical corruption.

Try also to boot using another kernel. Press SHIFT during boot to see the Grub boot menu and select a different kernel version.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I ended up reinstalling the OS and now it seems to be working fine.

Comment: Welcome. Check the disk for any issues: `sudo smartctl --all /dev/nvme0n1` You can also run a short or long SMART test. Check also kernel log for any disk errors.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Will do.

Answer (score 2):

There's really not enough here to tell, except that it looks like a hardware failure, as it's happening this early in boot. But if it was my machine, I'd guess first possibility would be hard drive failure, second would be memory failure. You may have trouble finding memory for an older machine, but you can probably replace the hard drive and reinstall Linux easily enough, and see if the error reappears.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I ended up reinstalling the OS and now it seems to be working fine.